# can dataflows connect to data lake as a datasource

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-lake, dataflow

I'm trying to connect dataflow (powerBI) to data lake gen2 to get data. I can't see the connector, does anyone knows if this feature is available?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for . As called out this is still in preview 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-connect-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2

Comment: I read the article, but it seems that you use data lake as a repository for the dataflow, not that you access a data lake as a data source!!!